# After creating fresh asp.net project in program.cs file i get error for builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When i created a asp.net 7 project in the program.cs file i see 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSwaggerGen' and no accessible extension method 'AddSwaggerGen' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to reinstall Swashbuckle.AspNetCore or update, im not able to do it i get Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'CodePulse' error i also see warning icon for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore dependency installed.

Comment: This might be due to a missing or incompatible Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package reference. Check if you have installed the correct version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore compatible with ASP.NET Core 7. If no compatible version is available, consider using the built-in OpenAPI (Swagger) support that comes with ASP.NET Core 7. Ensure the NuGet package source is configured correctly, rebuild the solution, and resolve any package restore errors or conflicts

Comment: Actually I Saw that i'm not able install any nuget packages i tried to reduce the version, clear nuget cache, set the package source to all earlier it was nuget.org and also rebuild the solution but still im not able to install any nuget package. earlier i had used vs 2022 and switched to 2019 for some reason now again after switching to 2022 version im facing this issue.

Comment: It was due to a library that i had used in my last project and after completing the project the license for that library was cancelled for me i forgot to remove that library source from nuget source after removing it im able to install packages.